# jquery slider needs only slider no change event

Tags: jquery, slider

I am working on the jquery slider needed some customization on that.

I need to make it behave like only fader movement slider . It should not move if I dont move fader . Not even change event will change the slider movement

```
$( "#master_volume" ).slider({
  value: 25.0,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "max",
  //animate: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 0.1,
  handle: '#myhandle',
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#volume").text($("#master_volume").slider("value"));

   },
  change: function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent) {
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "fader movement slider".

Comment: If I click anywhere its changing right now.I want is, If i click any where on the slider, It should not get change, It should get change if i move handle(fader).

Comment: ok then you can add a onclick event for body tag and return false witin the callback function. this way you will be able to stop the event . if possible add a jsfiddle, i can give it a try.http://jsfiddle.net